# SVN revision in Microsoft Office

Tags: svn, ms-office

I have some code documentation in MS Powerpoint 2003 that I'm revision-controlling in an SVN repository. I'd like to auto-insert the latest revision number into this document whenever I open it. I am using TortoiseSVN. I've been able to google up a macro or two that might work but wanted advice from experts. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you like to use "***keyword expansion***" with binary files (e.g. **.doc**) you have to use the following format:

**$keyword::______________________$**   (underscore = space)

The **::** ensures that the number of characters are always the same, otherwise you'll corrupt the binary word file.

But this only works until **Word 2003**.

This will not work for **Word 2007** because a .docx file is a ZIP file containing word data (e.g. xml). But it does not make sense to embed something directly into the ZIP content.

Maybe in the future there will be a **SVN contribution** which does the trick also for **.docx** file ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be possible to use the $Rev$ macro inside it with the Office 2007 XML formats, but I am not too sure what will happen with older formats that might contain binary data. You might need to tweak svn settings a bit so it sees .ppt files as text and not binary for this to work, I am not sure what is the default behavior. See svn:mime-type for this : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.props.html

Read this for detailed infos on $Rev$ replacement: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe SVN Won't touch binary files, and chances are if you embedded a $REV$ string in it something would break.

I know nothing about "Office Macros" either, but it would probably be preferable to

1. Have a text file with that revision string.
2. Have an office macro copy the previous revision string ( sans $REV$ for safteys sake ) Into the office file *prior* to saving.
3. Have the same office-macro that injects random garbage into textfile #1 
   every time the file is saved.

Its better IMO to write the rev string into the document on /save/ because that will eliminate the need for extra commits just for the sake of putting a revision string in the file, and it will also reduce dependency on that revision file in the event you share this PPT around without the aforementioned text file present.

Comment: Actually, subversion does handle binary files, it's just it won't attempt to merge new version with current, nor will it show the diffs or "blame": http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#binary-files

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I consider that the original question is still relevant today.

Did you ever try [SvnProperties4MSOffice](https://insights.oetiker.ch/windows/SvnProperties4MSOffice/)? The second version (V2) seemed to be designed exactly as an alternative to keyword replacement for MS Office 2007 and above. It uses TortoiseSVN in the background: the SubWCRev tool (packaged with TortoiseSVN) is accessed through its COM interface by means of a VB macro.
I know that the word "macro" can be frightening by itself but wait: this one is open source and quite simple. This makes it easily editable thus maintainable.

If you're interested to go further with the topic "MS Office & SVN" I invite you to [read one of my blog posts](https://gotomation.info/2019/01/svn-version-control-office-documents/). You would have a chance to:

- Install a SVN menu right inside MS Word, MS Excel and MS PowerPoint
- Diff two MS Office documents

*Disclaimer: I'm the owner of the blog.*